# regular expression for cpp_source files and c_source_files in python

Tags: python, regex

can somebody tell me how to express a regular expression for the following two strings:

```
c_source_files
cpp_source_files
```

I would like to analyze a text file which contains text segments beginning with the mentioned strings.

It could be expressed approximately as follows:

```
for result in re.findall('c(.*?)pp_source_files', re.S)
  # do something....
```

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
# 'c' optionally followed by 'pp', then followed by '_source_files'
r'c(pp)?_source_files'
```

If you need these strings to be separate words (so that things like `notc_source_files` don't match), then you can use word boundary 'matchers':

```
# \b matches a word boundary
r'\bc(pp)?_source_files\b'
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is even simpler than my RegEx.

Comment: Please check the edit. I have added the word boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
data = """
c_source_files
wutdafuc_source_files
cpp_source_files
pcpp_source_files
cp_source_files
"""
print list(re.findall(r'\b(?:c|cpp)_source_files\b', data))
```

Comment: They will get matched. OP has not specified if that is desirable or not.

Comment: Nice one, most people forget about boundries.